# Jump vs Warp to X in cloaky ships

Tags: eve-online

I'm a new player in Eve Online who generally is flying Covert Ops ships in nullsec for relic/data sites.  Since I need to return to hisec regularly to sell my goods, I find myself constantly passing through camped stargates.

My question is about the safety of the 'Jump' option.  Most of the forums posts I've seen regarding safe jumping typically reference "Warp to zero, then spam jump", which seems obsolete now with the "Jump" option (mentioned posts from 2012-ish).

Incidentally, many forum posts also advise for cloaky ships to "Warp to X" (where X is greater than 0) to avoid the 2km de-cloak and to slowboat--undetected--till 2500m where I can initiate Jump without being decloaked by the gate itself.

I'm looking for a more modern answer to the question: **can a cloaky ship safely use "Jump" to leave a system?**

I feel like I am constantly left waiting adjacent to the departing gate--decloaked and vulnerable--but I've never been locked (or even attempted).  Is this lucky or a by-product from already having initiating the new session?

Comment: While the accepted answer is fine, I would recommend explorers hunt for wormholes that take them back to null or high sec as an egress from nullsec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point where you're vulnerable at a gate is after you jump through, before you jump you're safe. The time you need aligning and/or the time needed to fly out of a bubble is the dangerous part.

When warping to a gate, during your warp you are invulnerable, and after activation of the jump sequence you're invulnerable as well. There is simply not enough time between the end of your invulnerability in warp and the start of the jump for an enemy to lock you.

The somewhat newer Jump command is generally safe, and pretty much identical to manually warping and then pressing jump. The "spamming" advice is mostly because you want to jump directly after your warp ends, and it is easier to spam the button than to determine if you're actually out of warp, and because under bad conditions commands can be lost.

There are situations under which you're not safe landing on the gate, sometimes your jump command will be denied. There are two big reasons for this, the first one is "traffic control". Sometimes you get a message like "You've been cleared to jump within xxx seconds" and your jump command is ignored. This has technical reasons, you get this message e.g. if you play directly after the downtime and nobody has entered that system yet. The really important part is that your jump command is cancelled when you see that message, and that the message is misleading and the time mentioned *does not* indicate anything useful. You might be able to jump a few seconds later, or not. Don't bother petitioning losses that result from such issues, I tried and it doesn't work.

The other important case that prevents you from jumping is if a system is too full, Jita often hits the population cap and you'll be blocked from entering. Spamming jump often works quickly then, as people constantly leave the system as well, but you might be exposed for quite some time on the gate if you're unlucky.

Under good conditions a single Jump command to the gate is perfectly safe, but if there are any network issues or server issues, this might not be the case. So you should always keep an eye on whether you actually jumped or got an error message.

Comment: My understanding of your answer then is that "Jump" is fundamentally a safe way to leave a system, and that only backend/technical hiccups will make it dangerous. Since I'm usually never logging in right after maintenance and I'm hanging out in nullsec (where population caps don't happen), I think I can continue to trust in 'Jump' then. Thanks!

Comment: I've been inactive for well over a year now, but it sounds like this new Jump command is just what the doctor ordered, at least when flying in high sec while not at war and with good sec status.  However, as an old school player whose flown through a lot of tense situations I don't know that I'll ever fully trust the client to jump me automatically.  :)

Comment: "There is simply not enough time between the end of your invulnerability in warp and the start of the jump for an enemy to lock you." This statement is provably false.

Comment: The jump command is issued only after your ship is detected to a) be uncloaked and b) within the 2k range of the gate. Once both are true your system sends the message to the server. However, due to lag and server ticks, a fast enough locker can get you and your ship before you have time to successfully jump.

Comment: All that said, the spirit of your answer is correct, although to be safe I generally warp to a near by celestial and scan, or warp from a celestial that I predict to not have a drag bubble.

Comment: @Pyrodante I've never seen that happen. I can see how this might be possible with enough lag, but with enough lag you can't rely on much anyway.

Comment: I have personally lost a shuttle in OMS to a gatecamp while spamming jump. No traffic control. Then lost my pod because I didn't know that causes a session timer. This is why you do not name your shuttle "leaf on the wind"